# Why isn't the last number printing?

Tags: java, arraylist

For some reason, the last number left in the Arraylist won't print and I can't figure out why.Little help please.
This is the result [88, 10, 6, 4, 2]

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(4);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(88);
        list.add(10);

        ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        int tmpNum = list.get(0);
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) >= tmpNum) {
                index = i;
                tmpNum = list.get(i);
            }

            if (i == list.size() - 1) {
                tmp.add(tmpNum);
                list.remove(index);
                i = 0;
                index = 0;
                tmpNum = list.get(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe what this code should actually do, because it does not look like a standard print out of the list

Comment: It's supposed to sort the numbers from highest to lowest. When it finds the highest number in first Arraylist it gets added to the second tmp one and removes it from the first one. Then it goes back until it's done, but when the last number remains it ignores the "if", and goes right to printing, I checked on Java Visualizer

Comment: Its doing exactly what you coded it to do, while I is less than the array lentth -1 update tmp, get rid of the -1

Comment: you are iterating over the list, but you change the size of the list by removing some elements from it in the second if, I guess that is the problem

Comment: It would be helpful to state in the question that the purpose of this code is to sort the list in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
tmp.add(tmpNum);
```

after the loop to add the last number.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) >= tmpNum) {
            index = i;
            tmpNum = list.get(i);
        }

        if (i == list.size() - 1) {
            tmp.add(tmpNum);
            list.remove(index);
            i = 0;
            index = 0;
            tmpNum = list.get(0);
        }
    }
    tmp.add(tmpNum);
    System.out.println(tmp);
```

Output:

```
[88, 10, 6, 4, 2, 1]
```

The reason the last number wasn't added is that once `list` contains just the final element (after the last time you call `list.remove(index)`), you set `i` to `0`, but then the loop's `i++` increments it to `1`, so the loop ends without adding the last number to `tmp`.

An alternative solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println (list.size());
    if (list.get(i) >= tmpNum) {
        index = i;
        tmpNum = list.get(i);
    }

    if (i == list.size() - 1) {
        System.out.println ("add " + tmpNum);
        tmp.add(tmpNum);
        System.out.println ("remove " + list.get (index));
        list.remove(index);
        i = -1; // this will cause the loop's i++ to set i to 0
        index = 0;
        tmpNum = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // since you need to find the max remaining number
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question. When i is 0, shouldn't the last number compare with itself and then proceed to add it too?

Comment: @mmir the problem is that after you set i to 0, the loop's i++ increments it to 1. This happens at the end of the current iteration, before `i < list.size()` is evaluated again. When `i < list.size()` is evaluated, it finds that `1<1` is false and terminates.

Comment: Understood. Thank you again.